# External lookup showing as blank in Lightning Experience

Tags: lightning-experience, related-list, lightning-connect, external-lookup

I have a writable external data source with 2 external objects:

**Car__x**

- VIN__c - Unique External Id (maps to VIN column in Car table)
- Plant__c - Lookup to custom object Plant

**Part__x**

- Car__c - External Lookup to Car (maps to CarVIN column in Part table)
- Plant__c - Lookup to custom object Plant

When a Part is inserted it shows up as a child on the Plant layout. However the external lookup field Car__c shows as blank *only on the related list*. If I view or edit the record the external lookup is there.

This issue does not exist in Salesforce Classic.

Is this an undocumented bug or am I doing something wrong here?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was caused by our OData connector; it had a bug in handling ORs in its query.